# converging sum of limits implies converging product

Tags: limits

Let $(x_n), (y_n)$ two sequences of positive real numbers.

Prove that if the sequence $(n + x_n + y_n )$ converges, then the sequence $(x_n⋅ y_n )$ converges.

Comment: how can $n+x_n+y_n$ converge? impossible

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_n$ and $y_n$ are positive real numbers, the first sequence $(n + x_n + y_n )$ never converges (its members grow arbitrarily large). So this implication is true by default.